# Accessing pandas Multiindex Dataframe using integer indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Dataframe:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex
index = MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip([21,22,23],[45,45,46]), names=['A', 'B'])
df = DataFrame({'values': [0.67, 0.87, 0.23]}, index=index)

Out[10]:
         values
A  B         
21 45    0.67
22 45    0.87
23 46    0.23
```

What is the correct  way to access the value for the element (22,45)? I have tried all the obvious alternatives but any of them seems to work:

```
df[22,45]
df[(22,45)]
df.ix[22,45]
df.ix[(22,45)]
```

I am using pandas 0.9.0.dev-1e68fd9.

Comment: Display bug (see below). One can use `df.ix[22].ix[45]`, but it is not ideal.

Comment: This has been fixed https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2051.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last two are the correct syntax, but there is a ([bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2051) preventing to display the result.

```
s = df.ix[(22, 45)]
```

works fine, but you can not display it